# Using a current transformer with an Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, current-transformer, arduino-uno

I have a current transformer [CR3110 - 3000](http://www.crmagnetics.com/Assets/ProductPDFs/CR3100.pdf)

It will be used to detect the state of different loads (100w, 1000w, ...). The intention is to use Arduino Uno, to detect voltage in the range 0-5V, like it is explained in [this](http://www.homautomation.org/2013/09/17/current-monitoring-with-non-invasive-sensor-and-arduino/) tutorial

One coil of the current transformer, which is used in the linked tutorial, has 2000 turns. I was wondering where could I get the number of turns for the current transformer, which I have.

The manual states defines a parameter Te (Effective turns ratio including losses), which is the only number resembling the number of coil turns.

Does the mentioned parameter represent the number of turns or is that information provided elsewhere?

Comment: Everything you need is in that datasheet. A more important question might be: Are you really expecting 100 A through the primary? If your turns ratio is ~3100, but you're only expecting say, 5 A through the primary typically, you'll a) be down in the mud and the CT might not behave like you're expecting and b) need to size your burden resistor to scale the current to 0-5 V, with some kind of over-voltage protection.

Comment: Thanks. The current transformer was bought by my colleauge, who is an electrical engineer. Im a software developer and was told I should use this. The max load, which will be used is 1000W@230V (~4.3A). If I understand you correctly (point a)), we should have bought a current transformer with a lower amp rating, because we will have trouble distinguish the read values?

Comment: Maybe. I can say that the wattage doesn't directly matter. If you had a 1000 W load that required 1000 V, you'd have a 1 A of current draw (P= IV). The CTs I work with on a daily basis are rated for 5 A (US) or 1 A (Europe), and we have often see metering issues with low currents. If you know your load's current draw, you can pick the appropriate CT so you're not wasting a bunch of headroom.

Comment: For a load like that, I might use a 5 A CT. The 5 A CTs I'm familiar with can handle 20 A for short periods and will pretty accurately let you meter primary currents from around 5 A.

Comment: Thank you. I should have written, that I only need to detect if the load is turned on or not. The reason we are using them, is to detect sticked relays. The CTs, which we currently, should probably do the job, right?

Comment: Your best bet is to contact the manufacturer and ask them if 4.3 A on a 100 A rated CT is far enough above your noise floor. Often, CTs running at less than 5% of rated don't work well, but the manufacturer would have more insight than me.